# How to resolve this error - Uncaught Error: '2016-' is not a correct date, datetime nor time

Tags: datetime, odoo, postgresql-9.1, odoo-8

I got the following part of code from Odoo community reference website for creating birthday calendar mark ups

### .PY file

```
class birthday_report(osv.osv):
    _name = "birthday.report"
    _auto = False

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.many2one('hr.employee','Employee', readonly=True),
        'dob' : fields.date('Birthday', readonly=True),
    }

    def init(self, cr):

        tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, 'birthday_report')
        cr.execute("""
            create or replace view birthday_report as (
            select
            h.id as id,
            h.id as name,
concat(concat(date_part('Year',current_date),'-'),to_char(h.birthday, 'mm-dd')) as dob
            from
            hr_employee as h
            join
            resource_resource as r
            on
            h.resource_id=r.id
                        where r.active ='t'
            )
        """)

birthday_report()
```

### .XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="view_birthday_report_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Employee Birthday</field>
        <field name="model">birthday.report</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <calendar string="Birthday" color="name"
                date_start="dob"
                quick_add="False" avatar_model="hr.employee">
                 <field name="name"/>
            </calendar>
        </field>
        </record>

            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_birthday_view">
            <field name="name">Birthday</field>
            <field name="res_model">birthday.report</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">calendar</field>
            <field name="view_id" eval="view_birthday_report_calendar"/>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            </record>



        <menuitem id="menu_birthday" name="Birthday" parent="hr.menu_hr_root" groups="base.group_user"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_view_birthday" parent="menu_birthday" action="action_birthday_view" groups="base.group_user"/>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

Error shows up when I navigate to January or previous year December, the following error occurs :

Uncaught Error: '2016-' is not a correct date, datetime nor time.

I am new to sql queries in Odoo, Anyone with suggestions on this would be really grateful. Thanks !!

Comment: Anyone kindly got a suggestion on this ? I need clarification on how the query works and also rectify me ...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend using `||` instead of concat.  That allows you to do multiple concatenations.

```
date_part('Year',current_date) || '-' || to_char(h.birthday, 'mm-dd')
```

Secondly I recommend casting to date, so

```
(date_part('Year',current_date) || '-' || to_char(h.birthday, 'mm-dd'))::date
```

Third, what happens if you just use psql and select from the view?  Are there malformed dates?  Or is something else happening elsewhere in your Python code?

Comment: Chris Travers, First of all Thank you very much, It is working great(the first solution). Really grateful for your answer